# Using calibre from the command line

Tags: shell, command-line, calibre

Using calibre from the command line, in debian testing, how can I insert a tag with the syntax being

```
    ebook-meta ebook_file --tags rhubarb
```

but for a range of files, but all by the same author so just need the tag of his/her name?

This is used for indexing and sorting out books on a Kindle.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way, assuming all the relevant files are in the same directory, is:

```
for f in *; do ebook-meta "$f" --tags rhubarb
```

If the files can be in various sub directories, use `find` (this assumes that the only files in all sub directories are ebooks. Since this is likely not true, you should use something additional like `-name "*.ebook"` or whatever extension your ebooks have):

```
find . -type f -exec ebook-meta '{}' --tags rhubarb \;
```

Comment: @ChrisDown argh, thanks, forgot the quotes which were the whole point of the answer.

Comment: @~/kindle-backup/34-wilbur-smith-Kindle-Collection]$ [9570]>; for f in *; do ebook-meta "$f" --tags wilbur-smith
> ^C
@~/kindle-backup/34-wilbur-smith-Kindle-Collection]$ [9570]>; for f in *; do ebook-meta "$f" --tags wilbur-smith
> ^C
Doesn't work, but I cant see why. Any ideas please?

Comment: find . -type f exec ebook-meta '{}' --tags wilbur-smith \;
find: paths must precede expression: exec
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]

Comment: There was a '-' missing before 'exec'.

Comment: @user205787 as Dubu pointed out, I had forgotten the `-` before `-exec`, try again with the modified answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must have the ebooks of an author in a directory. `cd` to this directory an run:

`for var in $(ls); do ebook-meta $var --tags rhubarb; done`

if the filename has spaces, you must modify the IFS (Internal Field Separator):

```
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS='\n'
for var in $(ls); do ebook-meta $var --tags rhubarb; done
IFS=$oldIFS
```

Or the same in a single command:

`oldIFS=$IFS && IFS='\n' && for var in $(ls); do ebook-meta $var --tags rhubarb; done  && IFS=$oldIFS`

Comment: Thanks for this but its not working, this is part of the puitput -

Comment: Thanks for this but its not working, this is part of the output - the output is too long for here but its at http://paste.debian.net/33088/ . I think that theres some problem with the 'cli.py' module itself

Comment: [NEVER parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and twice never when working with file names that are likely to have spaces.